Can I still use LSTM on my small datasets?
As for the datasets, I manually split it into three sets, consists of a Train Set (420 samples), Validation Set (140 samples), and Test Set (140 samples). When I run the datasets on the LSTM, the test accuracy only reach around 40% - 50%. And I could only reach around 80% for ML model. Could anyone give me a guide on which part should I adjust? Thank you very much for your help.
